# Interpretation of stokes theorem

Tags: calculus, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I recently solved the following task:

Let $A = [0,1]^3$ and $\omega = \dfrac{x_1^2 x_2^3}{1+x_3^2} \ dx_1 \wedge dx_3$ Show that this fulfills stokes theorem by showing that $\displaystyle \int_A \ d\omega \ = \ \displaystyle \int_{\partial A} \ \omega $.

That worked out really well. As the solution I got for both sides $-\dfrac{\pi}{12}$. The question is how to interpret this (maybe physically). I just learned about diffrential forms a few days ago and Im not sure how to interpret them. I think that integrating a 1-form over a curve gives the work that the vectorfield applies on a particle that walks along this curve. Is $-\dfrac{\pi}{12}$ something like the work that the vectorfield applies on the cube or something like that? Please keep in mind that Im not a physicist at all.

Comment: I assume that $[0,1^3]$ should be $[0,1]^3$.

Comment: Oh yes. Im going to change that immediately.

Comment: Why do you feel a need to interpret this physically?

Comment: I just wonder what this result tells me. What does it mean to get a negative value? Using the standard integrals the value would stand for the area under a curve or a volume but what does this value stand for? If this would just be a random number I guess the whole chapter would not be interesting.

Comment: This exercise was just an example to have you test the theorem. It doesn't need an interpretation just like $\int_0^1 3x^2 + 7x + 5 \, dx$ doesn't need an interpretation. It *could* represent work, but it could as well just represent the area under a function.

Comment: I know that this is not the point of the exercise. Im just interested. How do I know what this could represent?

Comment: By the way, something seems to be missing in the exercise. $A$ is 3-dimensional, but $d\omega$ is only a 1-form. Don't you need a $d$-form when integrating over a $d$-dimensional manifold?

Comment: Yes, this problem doesn't make sense. Your $\omega$ needs to be a $2$-form. I have no idea how you got numerical answers ... I'll tell you a physical interpretation after you make $\omega$ a $2$-form :P

Comment: Well I might need to take more care about formulating my questions. Of course its a $2$-form. Im going to correct this now.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the physical interpretation is that you're finding the flux of the vector field $\vec F = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -x_1^2x_2^3/(1+x_3^2) \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ outwards across $\partial A$. In this setting, $d\omega = (\text{div}\, \vec F) dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3$, and $\text{div}\,\vec F$ tells you infinitesimally whether you have a source or a sink (or neither) at each point; adding these up all over $A$ gives the net flux across the boundary.